# Can we format SD card present in nikon dslr from computer connected over USB cable

Tags: ubuntu, usb, sd-card, camera

I have to format the SD card present in dslr (Nikon) from desktop (preferably ubuntu) connected over usb cable.

I am using ubuntu desktop with libgphoto2 camera library to control my dslr. I can capture image, record video, copy images from camera to computer, delete images etc.. I have also checked nikon sdk but couldn't find relevant help.

I want to know first whether formatting SD card is possible or not. If yes, how can we achieve so.

Comment: Most importantly what do hope to achieve by formatting the card,  sencondly show the response to the command `findmnt` after connecting the camera and accessing files

Comment: Does the camera support a "Mass Storage" mode?

Comment: Nikon recommends only formatting SD cards in the device itself [& they assume from the camera's own interface] - that way you know it's correct. There's no functionality to remotely format from Nikon's own software whilst tethered.

Comment: @grawity, camera supports PTP.